# How to Show Alert of a Passed Variable onmouseover

Tags: javascript, html

This should be simple.... I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. In my HTML, I have

```
<a onmouseover="test(this.id)" id="ok">test me</a>
```

In my header, I have this script.

```
<script>
    function test(this.id){
        alert(id);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Function parameter names](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13) must be [valid identifiers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6), not expressions:

> *FormalParameterList* :
>          *Identifier*
>          *FormalParameterList* , *Identifier*

`this.id` is an expression, since it is a [property accessor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1), therefore it is a syntax error to use `this.id` as a formal parameter name. Change

```
function test(this.id){
    alert(id);
}
```

to

```
function test(id){
    alert(id);
}

// or
function test(foo){
    alert(foo);
}
```

Or simply

```
<a onmouseover="alert(this.id)" id="ok">test me</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
<script>
    function test(id){
        alert(id);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<a onmouseover="test(this.id)" id="ok">test me</a>

<script>
    function test(id){
        alert(id);
    }
</script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kyDMe/)